# LV creation on CentOS 7.7

Tags: centos7, lvm, udev

```
[root@kvm3 ~]# lvcreate -L 2G storage-3 -n testing
```

*/dev/storage-3/testing: not found: device not cleared
  Aborting. Failed to wipe start of new LV.*

It works fine with the following -Z option.

````
[root@kvm3 ~]# lvcreate -L 2G storage-3 -n testing -Zn
  WARNING: Logical volume storage-3/testing not zeroed.
  Logical volume "testing" created.





 [root@kvm3 ~]# lvcreate --debug -L 2G storage-3 -n testing -v
    Archiving volume group "storage-3" metadata (seqno 544).
    Creating logical volume testing
    Creating volume group backup "/etc/lvm/backup/storage-3" (seqno 545).
    Activating logical volume storage-3/testing.
    activation/volume_list configuration setting not defined: Checking only host tags for storage-3/testing.
    Creating storage--3-testing
    Loading table for storage--3-testing (253:8).
    Resuming storage--3-testing (253:8).
  /dev/storage-3/testing: not found: device not cleared
  Aborting. Failed to wipe start of new LV.
    Removing storage--3-testing (253:8)
    Creating volume group backup "/etc/lvm/backup/storage-3" (seqno 546).```


  [root@kvm3 ~]# vgs
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  storage-3   1  34   0 wz--n- <3.45t <2.49t 


How to avoid using -Z option ?
````

Comment: please post `vgs`output, `lvs`output, `lvcreate --debug -L 2G storage-3 -n testing` output

Comment: added in org post.